# php looping out form match new value with id?

Tags: php, forms

I'm looping out a form for every thing in the database write out it's position as  and also its id.

```
foreach ($foo as $thing) {
   $HTML = "
          <input type='text' value='$thing->position' name='newPosition[]'/>
          <input type='hidden' value='$thing->id[]' name='id'/>";
}
```

On submit i want to extract everyones id and new position so i can change it in the database.
How to i extract everyones position with their id??
somehow return $_POST['newPosition'] and loop it to changes everyones position value in the database (thats not a problem), my problem is how to match it with its id?

Comment: I think you'll get it from the index of array of your name attribute

Comment: provide structure of array `$thing` by printing it using `print_r()`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name the position fields with id -

```
<input type='text' value='$thing->position' name='newPosition[$thing->id]'/>
```

After posting the data -

```
foreach($posted_data['newPosition'] as $id => $position) {
    echo $id.' - '.$position;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

```
foreach ($foo as $thing) {
   $HTML = "
          <input type='text' value='$thing->position' name='newPosition[" . $thing->id . "][]'/>
          <input type='hidden' value='$thing->id[]' name='id'/>";
}
```

and then when you get the data you just get the key as well

like so

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){}
```

That way newPosition is tied with the ID :)

Comment: Is there any need for `hidden` field anymore?

Comment: Properly not @b0s3 - but since I don't know whether it's used other place I figured to leave it there, but aye, it could most likely just be removed.

Comment: Yup. The `id` is in the `array` now.

Comment: @b0s3 I'll just delete my answer :) No need to have two identical answers,  and  your's more clean / better written.

Comment: Appreciate that. But no need to delete. :)

Comment: thanks for both answers, i solved my problem. Did set b0s3 answer as the solution since as Epodax said it was more clean, and i did not need to use the hidden field or the extra [] in newposition[id][]